# change date and time on genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I am attempting to use a service that requires me to have the correct time on my emulator. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to change the time in Android Studio or my Genymotion emulator. Does anyone know how I would go about changing the time? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Genymotion emulator you can easily change your date time as expected.

Just go android settings-> Date & Time and you can set your own timezone and your date & time.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also do programmatically by running the following adb command:

```
adb shell date -s "YYYYMMdd.HHmmss"
```

Comment: I wasn't able to change time in my app even when I change time in simulator it was still at UTC and that command works. Thanks!